Behavior of backslash in 'a' command in GNU sed
I don't understand the behavior of the backslash in the a command in gnu sed.
The version of gnu sed used is 4.9.
$ gsed --version
gsed (GNU sed) 4.9
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
Paolo Bonzini, Jim Meyering, and Assaf Gordon.

This sed program was built without SELinux support.

GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.

Question 1.
Why is a blank line added when there are two backslashes?
Question 2.
I am aware that the backslash handles escape sequences, so the later backslash is output as a character.
However, there are different regularities when the number of backslashes is even or odd.
In each case, what role does the backslash play?
The following is the command that was executed.
One backslash
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\'
1
2
3

Two backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\'
1
2
3

Three backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\'
1
2
3
\

Four backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\'
1
2
3
\

Five backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\

Six backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\

Seven backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\\\

Eight backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\

Nine backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\\\\\

Ten backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\\

Eleven backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\\\\\\\

Twelve backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\\\

Thirteen backslashes
$ seq 3 | gsed '$a\\\\\\\\\\\\\'
1
2
3
\\\\\\\\\\\

...

posix implies a newline is expected after the first (required) backslash (note position of "text" is on following line, unlike for b, s, w, etc) but it does not seem to actually specify this. Adding anything except newline there will give unpredictable results (cf. gsed --posix or busybox sed) so is probably best avoided.

Perhaps the GNU Manual might be of help
